# How to set the space between characters or words in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried with the winAPI message SETCHARFORMAT, with CFM_SPACING in dwMask, and value in sSpacing, and it does not work. What can I do ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: It helps to design the page, for example, if you have text in two columns, and one column is longer than one line from the second column, by increasing the space you can add 1 more row to the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs on [CHARFORMAT2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787883.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> **sSpacing**
>
> Type: SHORT
>
> Horizontal space between letters, in twips. **This value has no effect
>   on the text displayed by a rich edit control**; it is included for
>   compatibility with Windows TOM interfaces. To use this member, set the
>   CFM_SPACING flag in the dwMask member.

Comment: Yes, but there is no alternative solution?